# es6 spread operator and uniques

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

The spread operator is very powerful with arrays but I find a hard time with duplication. I tried using `Object.assign` which has been successful at times, but others has given me weird results.

Any suggestiosn for an es6 way to use spread operator to concat arrays and deduplicate?

I am specifically using it for my Redux store:

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOCKET_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true,
        result: [...state.result, action.result.notification].sort((prev, next) => moment(prev.createdAt).isBefore(moment(next.createdAt)) ? 1 : -1)
      };
...
```

Comment: Check if the element in the array before you add it.

Comment: In the linked duplicate, check the ES6 solution. `Array.from(new Set([...state.result, action.result.notification]))` should work for your use case